# Recursive cumulative function

Tags: r

I need to write a cumulative summation function in R but I've been hitting a brick wall. The function has the following structure:

```
a*x1
a*x2 + a^2*x1
a*x3 + a^2*x2 + a^3*x1
a*x4 + a^2*x3 + a^3*x2 + a^4*x1
```

And so on. cumsum doesn't seem to work for this type of function. Is there any way this could be implemented in R?

Comment: Can you provide some sample input and the expected result?

Comment: I am looking for something like 1) .5*1=.5 (2) .5*2+.25*1=1.25 (3) .5*3+.25*2+.125*1 = 2.125, and so on.

Comment: You should add that to the question instead of having it as a comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since your recursion is

```
u[n+1] = a * ( x[n+1] + u[n] )
```

i.e.,

```
u[n+1]/a = x[n+1] + a * u[n]/a,
```

you can use `filter`:

```
x <- 1:5
a <- 2
a*filter(1:5, a, method="recursive")

# Compare with the expected values
a*x[1]
a*x[2] + a^2*x[1]
a*x[3] + a^2*x[2] + a^3*x[1]
a*x[4] + a^2*x[3] + a^3*x[2] + a^4*x[1]
```