# Working of stats::filter function R

Tags: r, signal-processing

I am seriously at a loss in front of this, what does the stats filter command in R do how is the "Convolution" method implemented. I understand the case when filter is 1 but for any other value of filter things get confusing. From another question in stackoverflow ([simple examples of filter function, recursive option specifically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372880/simple-examples-of-filter-function-recursive-option-specifically))  I understood how "convolution" works for filter =1
eg:

```
f1<-1,f2<-1,f3<-1
x<-c(1:5)
filter(x,c(f1,f2))
3  5  7  9 NA
#which translates to
x[1]*f1+x[2]*f2
x[2]*f1+x[3]*f2
x[3]*f1+x[4]*f2
x[4]*f1+x[5]*f2
x[5]*f1+x[6]*f2 #x[6] is NA
#filter other than 1
#filter<-c(1,2)
filter(x,c(1,2))
4  7 10 13 NA
#and not the below ones
x[1]*f1+x[2]*f2=5
x[2]*f1+x[3]*f2=8
x[3]*f1+x[4]*f2=11
```

and so on, what exactly is happening here? this might be trivial and because of the lack of understanding Convolution method, but I am not able to figure it out

Comment: To be clear, this was not `Filter` but `stats::filter`. And not `dplyr::filter` either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The filter is applied in *reverse* time order.  So the first element of the second example is:

```
x[1]*2 + x[2]*1 = 2 + 2 = 4.
```

etc.

The definition of a convolution includes reversing the order of one of the inputs.

Comment: Oh crud, my original examples in the previous question are actually wrong then for the convolution examples. Back I go to edit.

Answer (score -1):

Measuring the time difference between Bluetooth beacon pings

Example using the stats filter

Where AP is the Access point, and Location is where the test object was measured from

| Location | DateTime | Access Point | MAC | RSSI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Lab@(15m) | 2021-02-25 12:04:34 | "1838Y-1282400000" | "dc:0d:08:00:06:09" | -76 |
| Lab@(15m) | 2021-02-25 12:04:34 | "1838Y-1258500000" | "dc:0d:08:00:06:09" | -75 |
| .Many more rows omitted.. | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| lab-loadingdock | 2021-02-25 12:29:10 | "1838Y-1282400000" | "dc:0d:08:00:06:09" | -73 |
| lab-loadingdock | 2021-02-25 12:29:13 | "1838Y-1283400000" | "dc:0d:08:00:06:09" | -79 |
| lab-loadingdock | 2021-02-25 12:29:13 | "1838Y-1258600000" | "dc:0d:08:00:06:09" | -86 |
| lab-loadingdock | 2021-02-25 12:29:13 | "1838Y-1282400000" | "dc:0d:08:00:06:09" | -73 |
| lab-loadingdock | 2021-02-25 12:29:13 | "1838Y-1258500000" | "dc:0d:08:00:06:09" | -64 |
| lab-loadingdock | 2021-02-25 12:29:15 | "1838Y-1282400000" | "dc:0d:08:00:06:09" | -76 |
| LabOffice | 2021-02-25 13:07:06 | "1838Y-1258500000" | "dc:0d:08:00:06:09" | -76 |
| LabOffice | 2021-02-25 13:07:06 | "1838Y-1282400000" | "dc:0d:08:00:06:09" | -92 |

```
BLE_Beacon_data %>%
 dplyr::filter(AP=="1838Y-1283400000",Location=="lab-loadingdock")%>%
 pull(DateTime)%>%
 stats::filter(c(1,-1))
```