# Rolling percentage add along column

Tags: r, apply, rolling-computation

I feel this should be easy in base R but I just can't figure it out.
I have a simple dataframe, let's say it looks like this

```
tbl <-  read.table(text = 
    "Field1 Field2
    100 200
    150 180
    200 160
    280 250
    300 300
    300 250",
header = TRUE)
```

Now, what I want to do is create a function that will apply a rolling % addition, something like:

```
fn <- function(tbl, pct) {}
```

which accepts the dataframe above as `tbl`. It adds a percentage fraction of the current row to the NEXT row down based on `pct`, and rolls this almost in a cumulative fashion.

For example, `fn(tbl$Field1, 0.1)` would generate the following results:

```
100   (100 + 0.1*0)
160   (150 + 0.1*100 = 160)
216   (200 + 0.1*160 = 216)
301.6 (280 + 0.1*216 = 301.6)
```

etc.

I'd use a package solution, but would prefer base R as it helps with the learning process!  My longer term goal is to build a process the loops through each combination of field and pct so I can test it's effect in a regression model; hence my gut feel is that a function I can later apply is the way forward.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into the `lag()` function?

Comment: `filter` is handy here, `filter(tbl, 0.1, method = "recursive")`. See this nice post for explanation: [simple examples of filter function, recursive option specifically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372880/simple-examples-of-filter-function-recursive-option-specifically)

Comment: Nice. `filter` is faster than my answer too.

Comment: Filter appears to do exactly what I need. I had to double check ( :) ) but yes, it works nicely. I hadn't associated my problem with an auto-regression. Now, on to my next challenge which is how to apply combinations of this (this may be a second question I suspect!).  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`filter()` function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.4.3/topics/filter) is part of the `stats` package, which is base R. Keeping to one decimal place:

```
round(filter(tbl$Field1, 0.1, method="recursive"), 1)
```

Which would produce the following results

```
100.0 160.0 216.0 301.6 330.2 333.0
```

Comment: For the sake of clarity to OP's question, I specified only the column OP refers to. Of course, `filter(tbl, 0.1, method="recursive")` would do the same thing for the entire `data.frame`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `Reduce()` function as in the following.

```
cumpersum = function(x, percent = 0.1) {
  Reduce(function(x1, x2) percent * x1 + x2, x, accumulate = TRUE)
}

dat <- data.frame(
  Field1 = c(100, 150, 200, 280, 300, 300),
  Field2 = c(200, 180, 160, 250, 300, 250)
)

dat$Field1cumper <- cumpersum(dat$Field1, .1)
dat

#   Field1 Field2 Field1cumper
# 1    100    200        100.0
# 2    150    180        160.0
# 3    200    160        216.0
# 4    280    250        301.6
# 5    300    300        330.2
# 6    300    250        333.0
```

Comment: Very glad to learn about `Reduce()`, but in this application it is a lot slower than the dopey `for` loop.

Comment: There is a slightly faster `purrr::accumulate()` function. But I think `stats::filter()` is built for the exact purpose of the OP. `Reduce()` is what came immediately to my mind since this problem is a type of *folding* or *reducing* problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write a solution with just base R and learning programming from the very basics using a `for` loop and indexes, you could just know that you can write a function whose corpus look like the following:

```
solution= tbl$Field1
for (i in 1:length(tbl$Field1)) {

  if (i==1) {
    solution[1] = tbl$Field1[1] 
  } else {
    solution[i] = tbl$Field1[i] + pct * solution[i-1]
  }
}
```

though I would recommend to take a look to more advanced solutions. The `lag` function already mentioned could be handy.

Answer (score 1):

It's tempting to figure out a solution that doesn't involve explicit looping, but I couldn't think of one. You can decompose the desired result into a sum of numbers multiplied by `pct^c(0, 1, 2, ...)` but I think that just makes you do a lot of extra calculation. So my solution would be simply:

```
fn = function(x, pct) {
  n = length(x)
  result = NA*x
  last_result = 0
  for(i in 1:n) {
    result[i] = last_result = x[i] + last_result*pct
  }
  return(result)
}

fn(tbl$Field1, 0.1)

# [1] 100.000 160.000 216.000 301.600 330.160 333.016
```